# return text between two characters

Tags: regex

My regex is matching a string like *between a tab or comma and a colon*.

> (?<=\t|,)([a-z].*?)(:)

This returns a string: **app_open_icon:**

I would like the regex to remove the `:` appended and return **app_open_icon** only.

How should I chnage this regex to exclude `:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `(?<=\t|,)[a-z].*?(?=:)`

```js
const regex = /(?<=\t|,)[a-z].*?(?=:)/;
const text='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,app_open_icon:consectetur adipiscing...';
const result = regex.exec(text);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use lookarounds, you can use a capture group.

```
[\t,]([a-z][^:]*):
```

- `[\t,]` Match either a tab or comma
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[a-z][^:]*` Match a char in the range a-z and 0+ times any char except `:`
- `)` Close group 1
- `:` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KPG7bb/1)

```js
const regex = /[\t,]([a-z][^:]*):/;
const str = `,app_open_icon:`;
const m = str.match(regex);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

---

To get a match only using lookarounds, you can turn the matches into lookarounds, and omit the capture group 1:

```
(?<=[\t,])[a-z][^:]*(?=:)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UTEJ5y/1/)

```js
const regex = /(?<=[\t,])[a-z][^:]*(?=:)/;
const str = `,app_open_icon:`;
const m = str.match(regex);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have achived that with your regex.

Positive Lookbehind : `(?<=\t|,)` check for comma or tab before start of match

First capturing group : `([a-z].*?)` captures everything before `:` and after `,` or `\t`

Second capturing group : `(:)` captures `:`

Just extract the first captuaring group of your match.

[Check regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5XJBwU/1)